# MSSQL Restoring database giving error that unable to open physical file and operating system error 0 (null), I am unable to restore this data base

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore this database from
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/wide-world-importers-v1.0
but getting this below error. Help on this will much more appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. I had no problems restoring the database. Did you change any default configuration during restoration?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72670704/edit) your question to include the full error message - as text, not screen shot(s). You can directly copy the text from this dialog (that's a scrolling textbox right there) or use the Copy button sitting just below it (under the text "Program Location").

Comment: Try a manual restore using T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

The following Github issue suggests that the WorldWideImporters sample database requires the FILESTREAM capability: [Restore database backup onto mounted directory with FILESTREAM #122](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/122)

> Error: Unable to open the physical file "C:\Temp\WideWorldImporters_InMemory_Data_1" Operating system error 0: "(null)"
>
> ...
>
> **nocentino** commented on 6 Jan 2021
>
> Hi there, Filestream is not supported in SQL Server on Linux and Docker containers. Check out this link for more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported

From your screen shot it appears that you are using SQL Server Express's LocalDB which also does not support FILESTREAM, ref: [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb#restrictions):

> **Restrictions**
>
> - LocalDB cannot be managed remotely via SQL Management Studio.
> - LocalDB cannot be a merge replication subscriber.
> - **LocalDB does not support FILESTREAM.**
> - LocalDB only allows local queues for Service Broker.
> - An instance of LocalDB owned by the built-in accounts such as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` can have manageability issues due to Windows file system redirection. Instead use a normal Windows account as the owner.